how to import my js file to the main/index.js pre-compilation , not after compilation?

I use electron-vite command pnpm create @quick-start/electron init a project

and then i create a js filegetAuthKey.js in src/main/ next to index.js

last i require getAuthKey.js in src/main/index.js,like this:


import { app, BrowserWindow, ipcMain, shell } from "electron";
import { join } from "path";
import { electronApp, is, optimizer } from "@electron-toolkit/utils";
import icon from '../../resources/icon.png?asset'

const getAuthKey = require("./getAuthKey");            <--------------here
const { execSync } = require("child_process");
const iconv = require("iconv-lite");


then i get error

App threw an error during load
Error: Cannot find module './getAuthKey.js'


check the package.json and i find the problem

{
  "name": "xxx",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "An Electron application with Vue",
  "main": "./out/main/index.js",                        <----------------here
  
  
  
}



then i change code toconst getAuthKey = require("../../src/main/getAuthKey");
ok, code run ,i know require is to out/main/index.js not pre-compilation.
but i want to require my js file to src/main/index.js,what should i do?

i want to require my js file to src directory not out directory


I fix it
use ES not CommonJS to expotrs and import my js file.
such as

export function getAuthKey() {}

import { getAuthKey } from './getAuthKey'

not like this
module.exports = { getAuthKey };

const {getAuthKey} = require('./getAuthKey');

